# Question about logic simplification

Tags: logic

If I had to simplify ~(p^q)v~(~p^q)
so first I would distribute and get: (~pV~q) v (pv~q)

After distributing can I drop the parentheses and combine? What would be the next step in simplifying?

Comment: Should be $$(\neg p\vee \neg q)\vee  (p\vee \neg q)$$

Comment: my bad. After that step how would you go about simplifying?

Comment: From there you can regroup to get $(p \vee \neg p) \vee \neg q$ which is always true. Or see my answer below

Comment: Can I regroup it like (~pvp)v(~qv~q) or are there specific rules about how to regroup?

Comment: $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are commutative and associative (and distribute over one another).

Comment: ok so then it would reduce to p v ~q correct?

Comment: No. I already told you what it simplifies to

Comment: isn't ~p v p simply p?

Comment: of course not. ~p v p is always true. p can be false.

Comment: ok so it reduces to T V ~q

Comment: which is just T.

Comment: Makes sense, thats because an or statement is only false if both statements or false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17627/discussion-between-lil-and-david-peterson).

Answer (score 1):

You better apply the De Morgan laws to move the molecular negation to an atomic one, obtaining:

> $(\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg\neg p \vee \neg q)$

Now since the commutativity of the disjunction you got:

> $(\neg p \vee \neg\neg p) \vee \neg q $

Double negation law provides us the next step:

> $(\neg p \vee p) \vee \neg q$

Now, since the first disjunct is a tautology, we have:

> $\top \vee \neg q$

And finally:

> $\top$